# The Klein-Gordon equation Green's function.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, greens-function

How would I go about solving the following integral?
\begin{equation}
G_\text{ret}(x-x')=i\theta(t-t')\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{p} }{(2\pi)^32E}\left[e^{-iE(t-t')+i\mathbf{p}\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')}-e^{iE(t-t')+i\mathbf{p}\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')}\right],
\end{equation}
where $E=+\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$. Apparently the answer is
\begin{equation}
G_\text{ret}(x-x')=\theta(t-t')\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\delta((x-x')\cdot(x-x'))-\frac{m}{4\pi}J_1(m(x-x)\cdot(x-x'))\right],
\end{equation}
where $J_1$ is a Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Are you sure of $m(x-x)$?

Comment: That is what it says in the source. It is page 7 of http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/gonsalves/aqm/lectures/03/lec-03.pdf.